# jinja2: How to load includes only (don't render tags)?

Tags: jinja2

Given the following files:

`tmpl.j2`

```
{% include 'a.j2' %}

{% for x in xs %}- x {{name}}
{% endfor %}
```

`a.j2`

```
{% include 'b.j2' %} World!
```

`b.j2`

```
Hello
```

Does jinja2 have an API that allows to only load the includes (flatten the template) and not run anything else?

The goal would be to end up with:

```
Hello World!

{% for x in xs %}- x {{name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [`raw`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#escaping)  is what you are looking for?

```
{% raw %}
    {% for x in xs %}- x {{name}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endraw  %}
```

Comment: That's indeed a very valid solution! Do you have an alternative that does not require to alter the source template?

Comment: @PhilippeHebert I unfortunately do not, but I'm not sure if there is a solution without modifying the source. I'd have to research that